# How to open a Word document with its URL using VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, ms-word

I need to open an online Word document with its URL and copy the text and then paste it to a mail using VBA Excel, the thing is I managed to do it with a local Word document but cannot do it with the URL of the document in SharePoint, here is a part of my code:

```
 Dim OutlookApp As Object
 Dim wd As Object, editor As Object
 Dim doc As Object
 Dim oMail As MailItem
 Dim docPath As String

Set wd = CreateObject("Word.Application")
docPath = "https:....." 

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open(docPath)

    doc.Content.Copy
    doc.Close False
    
    With oMail
        .BodyFormat = olFormatRichText
        Set editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
        editor.Content.Paste
        .Display
    End With
```

I was expexting it to work as it did with a local Word document, but i cant manage to make it work with the online Word document's URL

Comment: Did you try searching SO for an answer? Putting the following text in the search box will give you previously answered questions:  [vba] open sharepoint

Comment: Yes, i found the solution, its the wey the URL in the string is copied, juest had to remove the GUID from the linked and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Information about link, what error and in which line would make solving the problem much easier.

Nevertheless, basing on given information, I guess that the code crashes on command

```
doc.close
```

If it is it, the problem is in the file path (I guess the file is on Share Point) - Share Point automaticaly adds information to open the file in Read Only Mode, therefore this code would crush unable to correctly close the file.

Check if the file path contains

> :x:/r/

if it does, remove it, this should solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, the code does not crash and its on a sharpoint ( except that it appears with /:w/r/ ) i erased it and still does not work, what happens is that i belive the text from the URL isnt copying, so when i paste it on the email nothing appears, like it does when i use a local word document

Comment: If you erased "/:w/r/", then the path is incorrect, you have to leave one "/". What Error at what line do you have?

Comment: Yes, sorry i did tried it like that it was a typo, but the error is in the line where the URL is open (set doc = wd.Documents.open(docPath)), and the information is copied (doc.Content.Copy)