# Insert Word content from Onedrive into a separate Word document

Tags: vba, ms-word, onedrive

I'm trying to insert the contents of a single Word document that is in the cloud to another Word document, which in most cases would be a local file.  This would be used to allow a user to pull in the relevant content while ignoring and omitting unneeded sections as they are progressing through the document. In other words, there's a main document, and I want to give users the ability to pull in content from multiple appendices, but only the ones they need.

This is very simple when the files are local.

```vb
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Working\test.docx", Link:=True
```

This works flawlessly. However, when I attempt to pull in a file from OneDrive, replacing the local address with a direct link to the shared file, or using the "copy link" option which assigns a unique URL, it creates an error.

Is there a way to pull cloud based Word documents into a local Word document this way?

Works with local file:

```vb
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
Selection.InsertFile FileName:="C:\Working\test.docx", Link:=True
```

Fails with OneDrive based file:

```vb
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
Selection.InsertFile FileName:="https://fakeurl-my.sharepoint.com/:w:/g/personal/fakeurl/ETd_aIr481Bn0geGvC-KGgBmKgY1eL7PWbzTZkevHZzWw?e=CzJK", Link:=True
```

Comment: Most recent question on this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77107230/how-to-open-a-word-document-with-its-url-using-vba-excel

Comment: Open the file directly from OneDrive in Word, then run `Debug.Print ActiveDocument.FullName` and copy the path from the Immediate pane.